# writing string cell matlab

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I load a cell string using  `[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('c:/wrd2.xls');`  it seem that the cell `txt` ideed contains all the strings, but when I am trying to look inside it, using `txt(1)` or `txt{1}` it returns `{""}`. and I also can't write it to another file, using `xlswrite('filenamve',txt)`.
any ideas?
thank you
ariel

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example, it is difficult to determine what the problem is.

The most obvious cause of `txt(1)` being blank is that the first Excel cell that you read did not contain text.  (Perhaps it was empty or contained a number.)

If your call to `xlswrite` isn't working, then the first thing to do is to *read the error message*.  Perhaps you are trying to write to a location that doesn't exist, or you've done something peculiar to the variable `txt`.  If you don't understand the error message then tell us what it says, and we can try to provide more help.